# Does BreezeJS support ordering by complex clauses

Tags: odata, breeze

I'm trying to figure out if there is any possibility to translate the next request into BreezeJS.

Pseudo Code:

```
orderby=(FIRST_PROP eq '12345') desc
```

Breeze syntax:

```
var query = new EntityQuery("Todos").where(predicate).orderBy('(FIRST_PROP eq "12345") desc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. We don't stray from the OData spec and I don't believe there is anything like expressions in orderBy clauses. It's not a bad idea. But it would be a difficult requirement to fulfill and hardly anyone (MS included) implements that complete spec as it is today.